Lost Ryzen 7 boost after Kernel upgrade to 6.8
I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04 from Kernel 5.15.0-119-generic to 6.8.0-40-generic.
On Kernel 5, the following
sudo sh -c "echo '1'> /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost"

would enable my Ryzen 7 4700U to zoom up to 3.9GHz when required.
Setting the flag to 0 would limit the CPU to around 1.8 or so.
However, since upgrading to kernel 6.8, the layout has changed and that command now returns a "no such file or directory".
I've googled and googled and lost myself in a spin over AMD pstate vs acpi and gotten nowhere (FWIW, I'm using acpi_cpufreq rather than amd_pstate despite enabling it in kernel parameters.
Surely I need to set the same flag elsewhere?

Please edit the question and state the full kernel number.
